# Airflow Custom MySQL Operator get_records with session parameters

Tags: python, mysql, airflow

I'm trying to run a MySQL query in airflow that requires a session parameter to be set prior to running the query.  If I pass both statements together, the get_records operator errors because the first statement doesn't return any data.  How can I set this session parameter and then return the results of my query?

MySQL Sample:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=2294867295;
SELECT ...query to return data...;
```

This is the related airflow code:

```
    def get_records(self, query, hook):
    results = list(hook.get_records(query))
```